# How do I insert the results of a cursor into a collection in the MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Sorry if this is such a basic question but I can't seem to find an example of how to do this anywhere.  I want to write a shell script that constructs a document from a find and insert the results into another collection...something like the following, but the following doesn't work:

```
cursor = db.Patients.find({},{"patient_id":1})
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    db.newCollection.insertOne(cursor.next());
}
```

When I run this, nothing is populated to the newCollection collection, but I don't get errors either.

Comment: not sure about shell scripting part, but I added two variant approaches below for your reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work if you declare `cursor` as a variable to keep the shell from iterating over the cursor for you:

```
var cursor = db.Patients.find({},{"patient_id":1})
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    db.newCollection.insertOne(cursor.next());
}
```

But you may also want to have new `_id` values assigned to the inserted docs, so you can exclude the original `_id` values from the docs as:

```
var cursor = db.Patients.find({},{"patient_id":1, _id:0})
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    db.newCollection.insertOne(cursor.next());
}
```

Comment: So your first example was the closes to what I had.  Basically, as you said, I just needed to declare "cursor" as a var.

Comment: short and sweet :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator in aggregation framework.

Try this mongo query:

```
db.Patients.aggregate([
{$project:{"patient_id":1}},
{$out: "NewCollection"}

])
```

Or use [db.eval()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/)

```
db.eval(function(patient_id){
          var docs = db.Patients.find( { patient_id: patient_id } ).toArray();
          db.NewCollection.insert(docs);
          return docs;
}, 1);
```

Or use [`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)

```
db.Patients.find({"patient_id":1}).forEach(
   function(doc){db.Newcollection.insert(doc);}
)
```